# Graphically representing relations of ordered pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am having problems trying to picture what this relation of ordered pairs 'looks' like:

Let R be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that ((a, b),(c, d)) ∈ R if and
only if ad = bc.

I am studying relations and set theory but none of the questions were presented in this manner yet.

How i picture this relation is:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        (a,a) & (b,a) & (c,a) & (d,a) \\
        (a,b) & (b,b) & (c,b) & (d,b) \\
        (a,c) & (b,c) & (c,c) & (d,c) \\
        (a,d) & (b,d) & (c,d) & (d,d) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Geometrically: If you look at the usual integer lattice in $\mathbb R^2$ then your relation is "the line connecting the two points goes through the origin".

Comment: Two rational numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ (of course $b \neq 0 \neq d$) are equal if and only iff $ad=bc$.

Comment: From my understanding, the relation is infinite, so I wouldn't visualise it that way- as a finite $4 \times 4$ grid. It really needs 4-dimensions to visualise- but I think an infinite grid like yours would do the trick- with all pairs "flattened" out along each axis. From my understanding, $a, b, c, d$ in the definition of $R$ are just "meta-variables". They just stand for arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean by "picture": To represent a general relation on a set $X$ with a diagram, you'd normally draw a subset $R$ of the Cartesian product $X \times X$. In your example, $X$ is the set of *ordered pairs of positive integers*, while your diagram only depicts $X$ itself.

To picture the relation $R$ in this sense, you'd need to start with a diagram of the "positive cone in the four-dimensional integer lattice", i.e., the set of *ordered pairs of ordered pairs* $\bigl((a, b), (c, d)\bigr)$ with $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ positive integers.

If $R$ is an *equivalence relation*, however, you can draw the set $X$ (as you've done) and then label elements of $X$ (e.g., with colored dots) in a way that gives distinct labels to members of distinct equivalence classes. (As the commenters suggest, your $R$ is an equivalence relation, though a proof of this may need to be supplied.)